# Time-lapse vs Drone Video Quality on Linkedin

Tags: video, after-effects, premiere, video-quality, render

When we post video on Linkedin, Time-lapase looks bad vs Drone video looks Crisp and clean. Video link and screenshot below.

See below

**Time-lapse footage:**

[image]

**Drone Footage**

[image]

Here is the Link to Original video: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/the-b1m-ltd_construction-architecture-engineering-activity-7104781406131609600-kElA?

Why is that and how to make time-lapse better.